# Does an electron beam in empty space generate magnetic fields?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrons

Does an electron beam in empty space generate magnetic fields around them just as with current in conductor.

Is it experimentally proven that two parallel electron beam would attract each other.

Comment: You might want to look up ‘magnetically insulated transmission line’.

Comment: Why would a moving beam of electrons be different to any other current?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, an electron beam in empty space does generate magnetic fields just as with current in conductor. However, two parallel electron beams will repel since the electrostatic repulsion is stronger than the magnetic attraction.

Comment: Is this a theoretical statement? I agree that the way we teach (pair production and annihilation), they should. But if we measure, do they ever attract?

Comment: @BrianCannard this is completely verified experimentally. It is an important factor in the design and operation of many particle accelerators.

Comment: can you please share a link to a peer-reviewed experimental research paper?

Comment: This is simply one introductory example. There are many more: https://cds.cern.ch/record/1982426/files/331-356%20Ferrario.pdf

Comment: I 100% agree with theory. Did anyone has published an experimental observation of what happens when two parallel electron rays run near one another, with controlled interval between electrons. Nature is a very complex beast even with the known physical effects.